# Concurrency control for GHC finalizers

Tags: haskell, concurrency, garbage-collection, ghc, finalizer

If you are interested, feel free to go over to the GitHub issue with all details [1], but I intentionally present an abstracted version of the problem here in hope that someone with more knowledge of GHC can guide us without having to learn all details.

We are calling a C API from Haskell. This C code allocates memory and has API methods to subsequently free created objects. We register these deallocation methods as finalizers [2] with the Haskell garbage collector for the corresponding objects. Everything works as expected without multi-threading.

However, when programs allocate and deallocate many objects and are compiled multi-threaded (`-threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N`) then segfaults start to happen. It turns out that most API methods, including the deallocation methods take reference a common argument which is not thread-safe.

We successfully got rid of the segfaults by synchronizing all API calls including finalizers by locking on this argument.

Also, when compiling with `-threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N --copying-gc` the segfaults disappear even without any locking. I searched and found the following sentence in the docs [3]:

> Setting -N also has the effect of enabling the parallel garbage collector

I understand this as: `-N` implicitly adds `--nonmoving-gc` which runs concurrently with the program.
**So finally my question:** Is it enough to set `--copying-gc` to guarantee that our finalizers and other parts of the program never run concurrently? Are there any other options apart from this or locking?

**GHC version:** 8.10.4

1. https://github.com/IagoAbal/haskell-z3/issues/27
2. https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Foreign-Concurrent.html
3. [https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/using-concurrent.html#rts-flag--N](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/using-concurrent.html#rts-flag--N)

Comment: Why do you want to avoid locking? In particular: is it because you are worried that it will block garbage collection when the lock is held a long time? (It won't, that's the whole reason the finalizers run on different threads.)

Comment: Locking is fine with me, I am happy to have the segfaults removed. But since we are a library I also only want to impose locks on users if they are required. Basically, we could say 'with this and this GC, the lock-free version is safe too'. Or even conditionally compile the locks based on the GC, but I doubt that is possible.

Basically just trying to find the minimal amount of synchronization needed in different compilation configs.